# Find most common values for each row consist of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have `pd.DataFrame` in which one column contains `lists` as the values. I want to create another column which consist only the most common value from that column.
Example dataframe:

```
    col_1
0   [1, 2, 3, 3]
1   [2, 2, 8, 8, 7]
2   [3, 4]
```

And the expected dataframe is

```
    col_1           col_2
0   [1, 2, 3, 3]    [3]
1   [2, 2, 8, 8, 7] [2, 8]
2   [3, 4]          [3, 4]
```

I tried to do

```
from statistics import mode
df['col_1'].apply(lambda x: mode(x))
```

But it is showing the most common list in that column.

I also tried to use pandas `mode` function directly on that column, it also did not help. Is there any way to find the most common value(s)?

Comment: why don't you keep the 3/4 in row 2? They are the modes

Comment: I totally missed that! 3 and 4 should be included.

Comment: Why is it empty for id number 3?

Comment: @Kermit yes the mistake has been rectified in the edited  version of the question.

Comment: I realized just now that only one can be accepted. Actually all of them are useful and solve the issue. so at the end I chose to accept the first answer posted.

Comment: @EMT - added to answer performance comparison

Comment: Obviously it is. I did not know how to find the speed of the execution. Also I did not paid too attention as my dataframe is small. But as always @jezrael , your contribution to specially in pandas  community is enormous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `mode` per group:

```
df['col_2'] = (df['col_1']
               .explode()
               .groupby(level=0)
               .apply(lambda x: x.mode().tolist())
              )
```

output:

```
             col_1   col_2
0     [1, 2, 3, 3]     [3]
1  [2, 2, 8, 8, 7]  [2, 8]
2           [3, 4]  [3, 4]
```

Answer (score 5):

Or just use [`multimode`](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-statisticsmultimode-in-python) from the statistics module.

```
df['col_2'] = df['col_1'].apply(lambda x: multimode(x))
```

```
              col1    col2
0     [1, 2, 3, 3]     [3]
1  [2, 2, 8, 8, 7]  [2, 8]
2           [3, 4]  [3, 4]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) - but it is slow:

```
df['new'] = df['col_1'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).mode().tolist()) 
print (df)
             col_1     new
0     [1, 2, 3, 3]     [3]
1  [2, 2, 8, 8, 7]  [2, 8]
2           [3, 4]  [3, 4]
```

Or use [`statistics.multimode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.multimode) if performance is important:

```
from statistics import multimode

df['col_2'] = df['col_1'].apply(multimode) 
print (df)
             col_1   col_2
0     [1, 2, 3, 3]     [3]
1  [2, 2, 8, 8, 7]  [2, 8]
2           [3, 4]  [3, 4]
```

**Performance**:

```
#[3000 rows x 4 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [195]: %timeit (df['col_1'].explode().groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.mode().tolist()))
537 ms ± 66.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [196]: %timeit df['col_1'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).mode().tolist())
699 ms ± 77.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [197]: %timeit df['col_1'].apply(multimode)
13.5 ms ± 1.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
from collections import Counter

col_1 = [[1, 2, 3, 3],[2, 2, 8, 8, 7],[3, 4]]
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':col_1})

def common(row):
    c = Counter(row)
    c = pd.Series(c)
    return c[c==max(c)].index.values

df['col_2'] = df.col_1.map(common)
```

df

```
     col_1            col_2
0    [1, 2, 3, 3]     [3]
1    [2, 2, 8, 8, 7]  [2, 8]
2    [3, 4]           [3, 4]
```